# Sorting an array with alternate smallest and largest values

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array, I was asked to sort it in a way so that the smallest values is first the, largest value second, the second smallest value third and so on. However when I input the values I do not get the required output.

Advise is appreciated as I have an exam today.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()

{
    int i,j,k,a[6],temp,min;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
        if(j%2==0)
        {
            min=a[j];
            for(k=j;k<6;k++)
            {
                if(a[k++]<min)
                min=a[k++];
            }

            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=min;
            min=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            min=a[j];
            for(k=j;k<6;k++)
            {
                if(a[k++]>min)
                min=a[k++];
            }

            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=min;
            min=temp;
        }
        printf("%d ",a[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that question did help me, but I want to know why my code is not correct.

Comment: This is still off-topic as given. Learn [ask]. And use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min` is used as an index(`min=j`) instead of value(`min=a[j]`)

Like this :

```
min=j;
for(k=j;k<6;k++)
{
    if(a[k]<a[min]){//if(a[k]>a[min]){
        min=k;
    }
}

temp=a[j];
a[j]=a[min];
a[min]=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some advice for you, although it's probably a duplicate. When you call `k++` when indexing your array (`a[k++]`), you always increment `k` although you did not finish the loop. So the `for(k.....)` loop does not pass all your other array elements.